# Why can't I install rust-doc?

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I just installed rustc successfully, and saw, apt suggested I got rust-doc also.

```
 $ sudo apt install rust-doc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 rust-doc : Depends: fonts-open-sans but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I suppose that there could be some spurious dependency in my repository; but I'm also especially concerned by that last line:

> you have held broken packages.

I'm not sure exactly what that means.

Since I believe that some of this depends on what repositories I am using, I include this information:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.2 _Sonya_ - Release amd64 20170628]/ xenial contrib main non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/maarten-baert-simplescreenrecorder-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/maarten-baert-simplescreenrecorder-xenial.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:deb http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

In response to a comment by David Postill in which he suggests I install `fonts-open-sans`:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install fonts-open-sans
[sudo] password for sam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package fonts-open-sans is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fonts-open-sans' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: "Depends: fonts-open-sans but it is not installable"  here is your clue. Install the appropriate font.

Comment: Welcome, please add the content of your sources.list `grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}`

Comment: @GAD3R I have updated the post.

Comment: @DavidPostill what is an "appropriate font"? Obviously I have fonts already installed. But ... why should documentation depend on a font in the first place?

Comment: @Wilson fonts-open-sans?

Comment: @DavidPostill that has no installation candidate; I've updated the post

Comment: The sources.list is OK , the package `fonts-open-sans` isn't available for xenial based distro [see here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/fonts-open-sans). See [rust-doc package broken ubuntu](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rustc/+question/667227) Comment #5.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for that info! I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

`rust-doc`is part of rustup installation . If you have installed rustup, just run `rustup doc —std`